# How to check if file exist locally and on a http server, and avoid 404 errors in the console

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-404

In my Angular/Ionic app, I have a big list of names, and I have to check if the corresponding image exists. Because sometimes we ship the image with the app, but sometimes we find the image later and we just put it on our server so we don't have to resubmit the app just for an image.

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in prodataSelect | orderBy:data.sort | filter: data.selectBrand.brand:true | filter: data.selectName.name | filter: generalSearchFunc | filterObj:['brand','modelStrict']" item-width="25%" item-height="35%" item-render-buffer="8">
    <a class="optionfuninit item-content">
        <div class="imagebox">
            <img class="imageoptionsmodel " ng-src="{{imagesUrls[item.imageName]}}" />
        </div>
    </a>
</ion-item>
```

I first check if the image exists locally (in the app), if not, I check if it exists on our server (http://...) and if not, I use a default image (default.png).

I check using this Angular service:

```
.service('UrlExists', [
            '$http',
            '$q',
            function ($http, $q) {
                'use strict';

                this.f = function (url) {
                    var http;
                    //UrlExistsDeferred = $q.defer();

                    try {
                        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        http.open("HEAD", url, false); //false is synchronous
                        http.send();
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log("An error on the XMLHttpRequest:" + err.name + "---" + err.message);
                    }

                    if (http.readyState === 4) {
                        if (http.status === 200) {
                            //UrlExistsDeferred.resolve();
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            //UrlExistsDeferred.reject();
                            return  false;
                        }
                    }
                    //return UrlExistsDeferred.promise;
                };
```

But the issue is that I get a lot of 404 errors in the console, and it's very annoying.

Do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have a better idea. You could create an API function on the server which would take a URL post parameter, check if it exists on the server and return 1 if it exists and 0 if it does not exist. On client-side you could send POST requests to that API function, passing the URL(s) to be checked. Make sure you do not generate an error on the server if the file does not happen to exist.

EDIT

There are [very good tutorial](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/)s about creating RESTful APIs in PHP, therefore I will refrain from their detailed description and will just tell you that you will want some `class` which has some `function`s and you will want to be able to call the `class`'s `function`s via [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). When you are more-or-less done with implementing this, you will want to test it using PHP. Try to make sure that you will have a `function` which will take a string for method name and call the method based on that string. You will need that when the client-side will send commands. When you are done with testing the PHP part, you will have to implement the client-side usage. It is advisable to establish a communication where you could send messages like

Check/IsURLExistent

to the server and pass the URL as a POST parameter. However, always keep an eye on security, never allow things which might be dangerous. For instance if you create a `function` to remove pictures, then you will need to check whether the user has the necessary privileges to do so, as bad people will send POST messages to your API trying to steal data from you, or harm the integrity of your site.

On the server-side you will need this functionality inside your `class`

```
public function IsURLExistent($params) {
    return (file_exists($params["URL"]) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

and invoke this `function`. On client-side if you receive 1, then the file exists, if you receive 0, then it doesn't exist. You might want to check the path in the URL, to not allow programmers asking for file names at other places via the API function. Basically parts of things written in this answer are probably clear, other parts are probably unclear for your current level of knowlegde. However, if you take the time to study a few tutorials, linked here or even not linked here, then you will find the implementation of such an API very easy. Don't forget, this study will not be in vain, as it will greatly increase your status as a programmer.

Comment: mmmh ! that's great @LajosArpad, do you think you could help me start the code ?

Comment: @Louis I am not sure I know enough about your server, but the idea, the way to solve described in my answer should set you started on the idea level.

Comment: yes I reckon that it is a good idea. My server is just php, are you familiar with that ?

Comment: @Louis, yes, I am more than familiar.

Comment: Ok ;) can you throw some php code to achieve that please ?

Comment: @Louis, I have given you links to tutorials and written sample code to check whether a file exists. Given further explanation to get you started. Remember, I am only showing you the way, it is you who has to walk through it.